# Adding a bindinghandler with jqueryui sortable in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm adding a sortable element on a table, it's a new requirement right at the end of the project so I don't feel I have the time to learn and add the knockout-sortable plugin. I tried adding a binding handler with a simple call to the element using jqueryui to make it sortable but ran into an error:

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'sortable'
```

The binding handler is really simple:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.sortItems = {
    init: function () {
        $('#itemGroup').sortable();
    }
};
```

and the table is a table with a data-bind: foreach, looping through an array of items:

```
<tbody id="itemGroup" data-bind="foreach: itemDetails, sortItems: {}">
```

Any idea where I could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems sortable plugin is not loaded when you call it. Check order of  tags.

Comment: That was pretty much it, I'm using require JS and I didn't notice I was manually including the jqueryUI plugin pieces. Sortable was not included.